# Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

Tags: magento-2.1, composer

I am trying to **install** the **magento2-pdf-generator2** extension, but I first need to install the mpdf library, I ran the `composer require mpdf/mpdf` command and then ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to clear the caches.

I tried the following example example and put it in a file called test1.php in the root directory:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

But I am getting an error:

```
[31-May-2017 16:30:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found in /home/public_html/test1.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/public_html/test1.php on line 4
```

all that I have in my test file is:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

I do have the mbstring, gd, zlib and bcmath extensions enabled. I am unsure why it isn't loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try code below

```
$mpdf = new \mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
For Magento version 2.0.x to 2.1.x - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
For Magento version 2.2.x & above - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy –f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```